# dynamic input value into django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a website in Django and I want to execute some calculations with a Python script.
I dont have any code in the models.py or forms.py, only in the view converting the python script for the Django (input to request and outputs to return).
My calculations has two steps. First request is a number, and the second request is a list of numbers where the size of list (how many input fields to display) is based on number from first request.
For example if first request is `3`, then we need to display 3 input fields. If first request is `5`, then we need 5 inputs etc.
My problem is in the html form. I am confused how to do that, how to create a multi value field, and how to connect it with my list for input?
I cant to create a dynamic input fields to writing the values for the input list.

my view request and outputs:

```
if 'num' in request.POST:
    num = request.POST['num']
else:
    num = False

for i in range(int(num)):
    if 'total' in request.POST:
        total = request.POST['total']
    else:
        total = False
    NList.append(int(total))


return render_to_response ('blog/calc.html', {'a' :a},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

a = my output list

my code in the html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Book</label>
  Number of number: <input type="text" name="num" value="Number">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">send</button>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group hide" id="bookTemplate">
        {% for i in num %}

  Enter a value: <input type="text" name="total" value="Total value">
        {% endfor%}
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

if I run this and click the Submit button, it doesnt show me anything - no error, no more inputs.

Comment: Instead of doing `if 'num' in request.POST` you can just do this: `num = request.POST.get('num', False)`. This will automatically set `num` to `False` if it's not found in `request.POST`.

Comment: if i do that then i take error 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: please show the *whole* `views.py`, and also `urls.py` - this way it's not clear if you use class-based views or not etc.

Comment: @hellas Can you confirm you wrote it like this: `num = request.POST.get('num', False)`. I think you are using `[ ]` brackets instead of `( )`.

Comment: @xyres correct,now i dont take error but not work again my form

Comment: urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.calc, name='calc'),
]

Comment: i think so we need javascript for this